# django project - problem because the sql server database has column names with spaces, i got how to use it in models.py but not in the template file

Tags: django, django-templates

the sql server I'm connecting to has column name with spaces in between
I changed the models.py but I don't know what to do in the templates file.

Code for the template file:

```
<div id="CPU Utilization" class="tabcontent">
<h1>CPU Utilization</h1>
<center>   

  <table border = "1">
    <tr>
        <th>SQL Server Process CPU Utilization</th>
        <th>System Idle Process</th>
        <th>Other Process CPU Utilization</th>
        <th>Event Time</th>
    </tr> 
    {% for datadisplay in sqlserverconn2 %}   
    <tr>
        <td>{{datadisplay.SQL Server Process CPU Utilization}}</td>
        <td>{{datadisplay.System Idle Process}}</td>
        <td>{{datadisplay.Other Process CPU Utilization}}</td>
        <td>{{datadisplay.Event Time}}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </table>
</center>
</div>
```

I tried the using the custom filters and defining attribute but it said it is not a registered tag library.

Comment: Those are the field names of the django model. They have to be valid python identifiers, so they cannot contain any spaces. Show the corresponding model code. Or are these dictionary keys?

Comment: thank you for the help but the problem was solved. The column names were from sql server and i couldn't change them but i defined them in models.py file and then used them in the html file and it worked.